# SQL Server Find the Date Range based on Start Date and Frequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm trying to create a function where I can give it any date and it can return a billing date range for a specific asset.

E.g.
Below I've got an example for `AssetBilling` table which tells me how frequently an asset should be billed based on the start date.

If I give the function a date: `25/02/2021` for the asset `Red Car` it should tell me that the billing period it falls under is: FROM `01/02/2021` TO `01/03/2021`

I have tried the follow CTE but I'm not entirely sure how to use it as I've not done it before:

```
DECLARE @InvDate AS DATE = '25/02/2021',
        @ID AS INT = 1 -- Red Car example
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT StartDate, DATEADD(MM, Frequency, StartDate) EndDate 
    FROM AssetBilling WHERE ID = @ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MM, 1, StartDate), DATEADD(MM, 1, EndDate)
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE
    StartDate >= @InvDate AND EndDate <= @InvDate 
)
SELECT *
FROM 
CTE
```

This is the result that I get:
[image: Result]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AssetBilling](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Asset] [varchar] (150) NULL,
    [StartDate] [date] NULL,
    [Frequency] [int] NULL,
    [BillType][varchar](50)NULL
);

INSERT INTO AssetBilling
(Asset, StartDate, Frequency, BillType)
VALUES
('Red Car', '01/01/2021', 1, 'Monthly'),
('Blue Car', '25/05/2021', 3, 'Quarterly')
```

Comment: Are there different types of billing types other than Monthly? What are they? When does a billing period stop? Does the person have to pay for the Red Car forever?

Comment: @Larnu -  there would be quarterly and annually potentially but this would just mean the frequency would be 3 or 12. I've simplified the table but I also have an end date which means the billing cycle will close once this has been added but yes otherwise it will go forever! haha Kind of like my netflix account >_<

Comment: Also, will the query always be for a specific id, or could it be many/all? Your example, as well, only gives one row; will the result always be one row? If so, why the rCTE?

Comment: @Larnu That's my mistake to mislead - the ID = 1 should really say ID = `@ID` as a declared value as it could be any bill. This example is just using Red Car as the row to review

Comment: I asked 2 questions there: what about of the date was larger; say `'20220617'`?

Comment: @Larnu Do you mean the date of the Invoice being larger than the Start Date?

Comment: I'm trying to find out why you have an rCTE, @Justin. You *seem* to only want 1 row, but if you only ever want 1 row, then why the rCTE? More than 1 vague example is important here.

Comment: @Larnu - possibility it may not need the rCTE, I thought if in the background recursively goes through the possible Start and End Dates it will stop when the `InvDate` is between the Start and End Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you need a recursive CTE here but to Larnu's point please show what you want to happen when the frequency is not monthly (to modify this query to support that I'd need to understand exactly what you want when it's quarterly for example, and the InvDate provided is in the 2nd or 3rd month of the period).

```
DECLARE @InvDate date = '20210225', -- avoid regional, ambiguous formats
        @ID      int  = 1;

;WITH src(StartDate, Frequency) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, StartDate, @InvDate), StartDate), Frequency
  FROM dbo.AssetBilling -- always use schema prefix
  WHERE ID = @ID
)
SELECT StartDate, EndDate = DATEADD(MONTH,Frequency,StartDate)
  FROM src;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very much a guess, with one vague example and no further example or explanation were given on request, but maybe this:

```sql
DECLARE @InvDate date = '20220225',
        @ID int = 1;

SELECT StartDate,
       CASE WHEN @InvDate > EndDate THEN EndDate --I assume you have an end date
            WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,StartDate,@InvDate) < Frequency THEN DATEADD(MONTH, Frequency, StartDate)
            WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,StartDate,@InvDate) % Frequency != 0 THEN DATEADD(MONTH, ((DATEDIFF(MONTH,StartDate,@InvDate) / Frequency) * Frequency) + Frequency, StartDate)
            ELSE @InvDate
       END
FROM dbo.AssetBilling
WHERE ID = @ID;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c9d3122fc5abaff99b70302cf5a669ea)

There may be scenarios I have no covered in the `WHEN`, but this is hard to know when, again, we have 1 example. Maybe this gives you a big enough clue.